# Open balls are convex proof?

Tags: functional-analysis

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Ball_is_Convex_Set

I don't know why they don't use this idea (I'm sure something is wrong in my logic):
$$
\Vert x+t(y-x)-v\Vert = \Vert x-v+t(y-x)\Vert
\leq  \Vert x-v\Vert + t\Vert (y-x)\Vert
< ( \epsilon + M) \leq \epsilon  $$
$M= t\Vert (y-x)\Vert\geq0$

Comment: The inequality $\epsilon + M \leq \epsilon$ seems to me to be incorrect if  $t \neq 0$ and $x \neq y$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch ahhhhh ,that's it !!okay thanks